# Regex pattern for VBScript

Tags: regex

I have to find string with 7 digits/characters length,The string mixed up with alpha numeric,can you please help to write Regex in Vbscript,

A text with 7 alphanumerical,

please help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you didn't search a lot.

Not quite sure what type of regexes VBscript supports, but at least one of these should work:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{7}$
^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]$
```

Comment: Im always confusing with Regex ,Newbie in Regex,thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

**Harder than it sounds**

In VBScript, using the `IgnoreCase` flag, a regex to match seven alpha-numeric characters would be this:

```
[a-z\d]{7}
```

However, if you want these characters to stand alone (i.e., you don't want to match a seven-letter string inside a twenty-letter string), you need some boundaries.

The end boundary is easy: we can add a negative lookahead `(?![a-z\d])` to assert that the next char is not a letter or digit.

But the beginning boundary is harder because VBScript does't support negative lookbehind. We could use `\b`, but it would rule out matches preceded by an underscore, as in `_1234567`. If that's not a problem, you can do this:

```
Dim myRegExp, myMatches, myMatch
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "\b[a-z\d]{7}(?![a-z\d])"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(SubjectString)
For Each myMatch In myMatches
    'matched text: myMatch.Value
Next
```

If the underscore exclusion is a problem, we'll use a capture group instead:

```
Dim myRegExp, myMatches, myMatch
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "(?:^|[^a-z\d])([a-z\d]{7}(?![a-z\d]))"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(SubjectString)
For Each myMatch In myMatches
    'Your match: myMatch.SubMatches(0)
Next
```